# My text doesn't show up inside UITextView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

My view controller contains an UIImageView and a UITextView below. This is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DescriptionViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *descriptionImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *descriptionText;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *image;

@end


@interface DescriptionViewController ()

@end

@implementation DescriptionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.descriptionText = [[UITextView alloc] init];

    self.descriptionImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.image]]];
    self.descriptionText.text = self.text;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.descriptionText.text);
}

@end
```

My code doesn't show up in textview, but I can print it using NSLog.
What could be the problem ?

Comment: Are you sure that your textview is there were r u looking? set background color or something

Comment: See ssantos's answer: you have to connect the textView component with it's outlet in Interface Builder. check with `NSLog(@"tx: %@",self.descriptionText);` at the end of `viewDidLoad` if it's null by any chance. and remove the line ssantos is talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're initializing a new `UITextView` here.-

```
self.descriptionText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
```

This way, you get a new `UITextView` not linked with the main view. Remove that line and make sure `descriptionText` is properly linked in your `xib` or `storyboard`.

However, if your intention was actually programmatically creating a new `UITextView` from scratch, then you'll also have to programmatically add it to your main view.

Comment: Correct. The same goes for the descriptionImage.

Comment: Ohh, I was testing something and forgot to delete that, this fixed my problem.

Comment: @rokjarc: how else can I load a string image to an UIImage if my way isn't good?

Comment: @rokjarc, I don't think so, the `UIImageView` is not being initialized again, just the `UIImage` content.

Comment: @vBx As for me there's nothing wrong with `descriptionImage`, it should show up correctly.

Comment: You're right of course. My eyes saw UIIMageView. Sorry for that.

Comment: Yeah, me too, I was adding your comment to the answer when I realized :)